# C# Fast Food Menu

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I'm writing a program that displays a fast food menu and it allows the user to select an item. Then, the user enters the quantity of that item, and can continue selecting items with specific quantities until done. What I'm having trouble with is finding out how to calculate a running total. I am new to c# so I only know the basics. What is the best way to keep track of the running total while using multiple methods? In addition, I'm open to any criticism in my code. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        bool ordering = true;
        string userInput;
        double itemPrice;
        double itemQuantity;
        double subTol;
        string response;
        
        void pricing()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter option 1, 2, 3: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (userInput) 
            {
                case "1":
                    itemPrice = 3.00;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have picked a burger.");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    itemPrice = 1.50;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have picked fries.");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    itemPrice = 1.00;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have picked a soda.");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not on our menu.");
                    pricing();
                    break;
            }
        }

        void quantity()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter quantity: ");
            itemQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        void subTotal()
        {
            subTol = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Subtotal: " + subTol);
        }
                
        while (ordering)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like from our menu?");
            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Burger ($3.00) \n2. Fries ($1.50) \n3. Soda ($1.00)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            
            pricing();
            quantity();
            subTotal();
            
            Console.Write("Would you like anything else? Y/N: ");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            response = response.ToUpper();

            if (response == "Y")
            {
                ordering = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ordering = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your meal!");
            }
                
        }
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"What is the best way to keep track of the running total"* - Store a value in a variable and update that variable with the new value any time it needs to change?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I'd look at using a List of objects and when they select an item add it to the list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: A _runningTotal_ variable just accumulates the calculated value of _subTol_ for each _while(ordering)_ loop

Comment: I have tried creating individual variables for each food item and using those variables to create a specific order. However, I am wanting more of a custom order feature instead. I will try using a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the
`If(response==“Y”)`
Part you can actually just say
`ordering = response == “Y”;`
Also, this would only accept uppercase y. String.EqualsIgnoreCase() or something similar would probably do a better job
`ordering = response.equalsIgnoreCase(“Y”);`

You could keep a list of how many of each item the person has ordered, like
`Int burgers = 0;` and so on.
Then for the total, you could get `3*burgers + 1.5*fries` and so on. However, if you want custom orders, using a struct might be better. For example, a struct could contain a type(burger or fries) and a price, depending on how many additions they have. You could also just add the price of each item to a total every time you order. This seems like a fun project, and I hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

For keeping track of total, the best approach would be to have a list of ordered items with their quantities, where you go and put each order from the user.

When you want to calculate the subtotal or total, you just go and compute from the list.

Here are some insights on how you can accomplish that, with some changes to the code you shared. Check the comments for details and reasoning.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1{
  // creating record classes to store structured data
  record MenuItem(string Product, decimal Price);
  record Order(MenuItem Item, int Quantity);

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      // better to keep your menu options & prices in a central place, 
      // instead of hardcoding them everywhere
      List<MenuItem> menu = new() { 
        new ("Burger", 3.00M), 
        new ("Fries", 1.50M), 
        new ("Soda", 1.00M), 
      };
      // this is a list to store the ordered items so far
      List<Order> orders = new();

      // moved most of the procedures to separate functions
      do {
        PrintMenu(menu);
        var item = InputItem(menu);
        var quantity = InputQuantity();
        orders.Add(new Order(item, quantity));
        PrintSubTotal(orders);
      } while (CheckIfContinue());
      PrintTotal(orders);
      ByeBye();
    }

    static void PrintMenu(List<MenuItem> menu) {
      // print each menu entry in a loop
      Console.WriteLine("What would you like from our menu?");
      for (int i = 0; i < menu.Count; i++) {
        // adding 1 to the index for printing, because in c# indexes start at 0
        Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {menu[i].Product} (${menu[i].Price})");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static MenuItem InputItem(List<MenuItem> menu) {
      // enter a loop, will be broken only if the input is correct
      while (true) {
        Console.Write($"Enter option: 1 to {menu.Count}: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int i) && i > 0 && i <= menu.Count) {
          // must subtract 1 from the index, because indexes start from 0 in c#
          Console.WriteLine($"You have picked {i}: {menu[i - 1].Product}.\n");
          // if the input is a valid int
          return menu[i - 1];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("That is not in our menu.\n");
      }
    }

    static int InputQuantity() {
      // same thing here, will repeat the loop unless the input is valid
      while (true) {
        Console.Write("Enter quantity: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int i) && i > 0) {
          return i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid quantity.\n");
      }
    }

    static void PrintSubTotal(List<Order> orders) {
      // using LINQ to iterate the list of orders sum up the prices x quantities
      Console.WriteLine($"Your Subtotal: ${orders.Sum(o => o.Item.Price * o.Quantity)}\n");
    }

    static bool CheckIfContinue() {
      Console.Write("Would you like anything else? Y/N: ");
      // will return True if the input is y
      return Console.ReadLine()?.Trim().ToUpper() == "Y";
    }

    static void PrintTotal(List<Order> orders) {
      Console.WriteLine($"Your Order:");
      foreach (var order in orders) {
        // subtotal for each order item
        Console.WriteLine($"{order.Item.Product, -10} x{order.Quantity, -4}: ${order.Item.Price * order.Quantity}");        
      }
      // total for the whole order
      Console.WriteLine($"---------- Total: ${orders.Sum(o => o.Item.Price * o.Quantity)}\n");
    }

    static void ByeBye() {
      Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your meal!");
    }
  }
}
```